# Calculator in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, calculator

i was making a calculator for a school project and the teacher told me what to do and it worked. or so i thought when i was cleaning the programme i realised it only works "+" and none of the other buttons.any help would be appreciated.

```
tempstr=my_text.get()
loopval=len(tempstr)
op=tempstr.index("+")
if (op>0):
    leftnum=tempstr[0:op]
    rightnum=tempstr[op+1:loopval+1]
    answe=int(leftnum)+int(rightnum)
    print (answe)
    my_text.insert(END,str(answe))
op=tempstr.index("-")
if (op>0):
    leftnum=tempstr[0:op]
    rightnum=tempstr[op+1:loopval+1]
    answe=int(leftnum)-int(rightnum)
    print (answe)
    my_text.insert(END,str(answe))
op=tempstr.index("*")
if (op>0):
    leftnum=tempstr[0:op]
    rightnum=tempstr[op+1:loopval+1]
    answe=int(leftnum)*int(rightnum)
    print (answe)
    my_text.insert(END,str(answe))
op=tempstr.index("/")
if (op>0):
    leftnum=tempstr[0:op]
    rightnum=tempstr[op+1:loopval+1]
    answe=int(leftnum)/int(rightnum)
    print (answe)
    my_text.insert(END,str(answe))
```

Answer (score 0):

`index` throws an error if the substring is not found. An error in tkinter stops the function but not the loop, so you probably didn't notice it. You meant to use `find` which returns -1 if not found.

Even better would be like this:

```
if "+" in tempstr:
    op=tempstr.index("+")
    leftnum=tempstr[0:op]
    rightnum=tempstr[op+1:loopval+1]
    answe=int(leftnum)+int(rightnum)
    print (answe)
    my_text.insert(END,str(answe))
elif '-' in tempstr:
    op=tempstr.index("-")
    leftnum=tempstr[0:op]
    rightnum=tempstr[op+1:loopval+1]
    answe=int(leftnum)-int(rightnum)
    print (answe)
    my_text.insert(END,str(answe))
```